# Check if Release Tag is latest on GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I've release two tags, `0.1.0` and then `0.0.1`. The latest release tag is `0.1.0`.

How do I check inside the GitHub Action if the workflow was dispatched by the latest release?

```
name: Test
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    branches:
      - main
  release:
    types: [published]
jobs:
  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - run: echo ${{ github.ref_name }}
```

${{ github.ref_name }} returns the tag version `0.1.0` or `0.0.1`, I want to tag Docker images in action the same as GitHub: as `image:latest` only if the action was dispatched by `0.1.0`, `0.1.0` is the latest even if `0.0.1` was dispatched later like displayed in the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: You could get the latest tag using git ([reference](https://gist.github.com/rponte/fdc0724dd984088606b0)) and compare the value with the `github.ref_name` variable.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, github context doesn't provide this information.

As a walkaround you can use git command to retrieve the latest version:

```
git tag | sort --version-sort | tail -n1
```

and then compare it to the current tag in the github actions context:

```
${{ github.ref_name }}
```

example:

```
  - name: "Set latest tag"
    id: set-latest-tag
    run: echo "latest_tag=$(git tag | sort --version-sort | tail -n1)" >> $GITHUB_ENV

  - name: "Tag Docker image as latest"
    id: tag-as-latest
    if: ${{ github.ref_name == env.latest_tag }}
    run: |
      ...
```

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the Github release that is marked as `latest` by the maintainers (does not have to be chronologically or alphabetically the latest created git tag):

```yaml
- name: Export LATEST_TAG
  run: |
    echo "LATEST_TAG=$(curl -qsSL \
      -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
      -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
      -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
      "${{ github.api_url }}/repos/${{ github.repository }}/releases/latest" \
    | jq -r .tag_name)" >> $GITHUB_ENV

- name: Do something when the current tag is the latest tag
  if: ${{ github.ref_name == env.LATEST_TAG }}
  run: ...
```

This uses the `tag_name` attribute in the REST API response ([docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/releases#get-the-latest-release))